# Firebase Hosting returning 500 internal error for Googlebot user-agent when using Google Chrome's "network conditions" tab?

Tags: firebase, user-agent, firebase-hosting, googlebot

I've got the following set up on my Firebase web app (it's a Single Page App built with React):

- I'm doing SSR for robots user agents, so they get full rendered HTML and no Javascript
- Users get the empty HTML and get the Javascript to run the app.

**firebase.json**

```
"rewrites": [{
  "source": "/**",
  "function": "ssrApp"
}]
```

Basically every request should go into my `ssrApp` function, that will detect robot crawlers user-agents and decide wheter it will respond with the SSR version for the robots, or the JS version for the regular users.

**It is working as intended.** Google is indexing my pages, and I always log some info about the user agents from my `ssrApp` function. For example, when I'm sharing an URL on Whatsapp, I can see Whatsapp crawler on my logs from Firebase Console (see below):

[image]

---

But the weird thing is that I'm not being able to mimick Googlebot using Chrome's Network Conditions tab:

[image]

[image]

When I try to access my site by using Googlebot's user agent I get a `500 - Internal error`

And my `ssrApp` functions isn't even triggered, **since NOTHING is logged out from it.**

Is this a Firebase Hosting built-in protection to avoid fake Googlebots? What could be happening?

**NOTE:** I'm trying to mimick Googlebot's user agent because I want to inspect the SSR version of my app in production. I know that there are other ways to do that (including some Google Search Console tools), but I thought that this would work.

Comment: Hi, can you please reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/bugs) with details of your specific site and the full 500 response you're receiving? Please reference internal bug id 150219808 when you do.

Comment: @MichaelBleigh thank you, Michael! I will do that!

Comment: I'm having the same issue, getting `Internal error` with a 500 response code from Firebase hosting with the `googlebot` user-agent, the request doesn't reach cloud functions at all. Already reached out to Firebase support, waiting for their reply. Case: ref:_00D1Ux0Jq._5003p2NdW6Z:ref

Comment: @AttilaMolnár Thanks! I'll reach them as well. And I'll mention your case so they can compare.

Comment: Ok .. same behavior .. thanks for posting this

Comment: Hi @cbdeveloper,i've filled an issue to firebase support and it seems to be resolved for now

Comment: I'm still encountering this issue, but the Firebase Hosting CDN (Fastly) is only returning the 500 Internal Error for a route that is an alias/rewrite for a Cloud Run container. Furthermore, it only happens when the CDN cache is empty. If the CDN cache is populated for this route, then it responds successfully. Will file another support ticket. Currently using GCP Monitoring Uptime Checks to keep the cache filled...

Answer (score 1):

Could you check that your pages are still in the Google index? I have the exact same experience and 80% of my pages are now gone...
When I look up a page in Google Search Console https://search.google.com/search-console it indicates there was an issue during the last crawl. When I "Test it Live" it spins and reports the error 500 as well and asks to "try again later"...

Comment: I will check tomorrow and let you know. So far it feels normal.

Comment: Just tested. Yes, they are still indexed and they are available when I tested it live for my home url.

Comment: And I just saw the Googlebot's user-agent in the logs from the ssrApp function. It has just visited my app for the Live Test that I just did. So it is working fine for the real Googlebot. It seems the problem is when you mimick its user-agent. Somehow FB Hosting is not accepting that.

Comment: Ok, good news for you :) Here's what I'm seeing... https://youtu.be/zwZTrRzqAxw

Answer (score 1):

I had a related issue, so I hope this could help anyone who encounters what I did:

I got the `500 - Internal error` response for paths that were routed to a Cloud Run container when serving a GoogeBot user agent. As it happens, if the Firebase Hosting CDN happened to have a cached response for the path, it would successfully serve the cached response, but if it didn't have a cached response, then the request would not reach the Cloud Run container, it would fail at the Firebase Hosting CDN with `500 - Internal error`.

It turns out that the Firebase Hosting CDN secretly probes and respects any `robots.txt` that is served by the Cloud Run container itself (not the Hosting site). My Cloud Run container served a `robots.txt` which disallowed all access to bots.

Seemingly, when the Hosting CDN attempts to serve a request from a bot from a path that is routed to a Cloud Run container, it will first probe any `/robots.txt` that is accessible at the root of that container itself, and then refuse to send the request to the container if disallowed by the rules therein.

Removing/adjusting the `robots.txt` file on the Cloud Run container itself immediately resolved the issue for me.